# Display an image to the user phone gallery

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, storage

I am working on a game which has a feature to capture screenshots and store them in the project folder in windows and in com.package file folder in Android. The 2 steps which were troubling are:

1) When I want to see the picture from the native gallery or through google photos application, I can't find the pictures. But when I search in the com.package folder they are present there.

2) How to create a separate folder in the phone internal storage for the game and store all the pictures there.

To save the picture I am using Application.persistentpath. Are there any other points which I am missing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the picture at the path that the Gallery of phone can access,

First, you should get the Read/Write permission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

You can set option in Unity Editor **"Player Settings" > "Other Settings" > "Configuration" > "Write Permission" > "External(SDCard)"**(https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html)

Or you can request the permission yourself(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html).

Second, you should save the picture at external storage like below.

```
using System.IO;

void SavePicture(byte[] texture)
{
    string path = GetExternalStoragePath() + "/picture";
    string fileName = "picture.png";

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/" + fileName, texture);
}

string GetExternalStoragePath()
{
    AndroidJavaClass env = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment");
    AndroidJavaObject dir = env.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStorageDirectory");
    return dir.Call<string>("toString");
}
```

Comment: The directory is created perfectly. But the problem which still exists is that i want to move the picture which initially saves in com.package file to the newly created directory.

Comment: If you move files to internal storage like "sdcard/Android/data/com.package/file/", you can't see pictures on the native Gallery app. Is it OK?

Comment: I am still not able to create a directory. Under the awake method, i am using Directory.CreateDirectory("/storage/emulated/0/" + "Folder"); . But the folder isn't created.

Comment: I edited this line `AndroidJavaObject dir = env.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStorageDirectory")`;
And did you get read/write permission?

Comment: I used "Player Settings" > "Other Settings" > "Configuration" > "Write Permission" to internal for write operations.

Comment: You should set "External (SDCard)" not "Internal".

Comment: Also, I have executed with changes, there isn't any directory created. The app crashes off when the directory is checked for.

Comment: What if the user doesn't have an SD card? Even I change it to external, it still crashes.

Comment: The problem is that when I generate an image or a video, it gets saved in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.name/filename. Now when i try to move the file to a new directory which is being created, the app crashes.

Comment: On develop side, the internal means storage that no one can access except application itself, but the external means that every application can access if it has read/write permission. So, you have to set External if you want pictures are displayed on Gallery. Refer to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: string path_1 = GetExternalStoragePath() + "/picture";
string fileName = "pictue1.mp4";
if (!Directory.Exists(path_1)){
       Directory.CreateDirectory(path_1);
}       
 File.Move(Exiting_path, path_1 + "/" + fileName);
string GetExternalStoragePath()
 {
       AndroidJavaClass env = new        AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment");
        AndroidJavaObject dir = env.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStorageDirectory");
        return dir.Call<string>("toString");
    }

Comment: I tested your code in my workspace, it worked well.
What do you mean `Exiting_path`?
And did you check if the src file was exist and if dst file wasn't exist?

Comment: I have figured there was a configuration problem. Thanks @Heejae Kim